# a better phrase for: I am running very fast

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

I want to write a book and wanted some help deciding the words I could use to enhance it. So the guy is running ***really fast***. How can I make it sound better?

Answer (score 2):

The best, most general synonym that I can think of for running really fast would be **sprinting**.

Answer (score 0):

He is running super fast.

He is running very quickly.

I'm running super fast.

I'm running very quickly.

He ran at top speed/is running at top speed/l'm running at top speed.

He's/l'm running like the wind/lightening.

He's legging it.

I'm legging it.

He's running at a fast pace.

I'm running at a fast pace.

He paced along.

I'm pacing it.

He's running like a bolt of lightning. Or bolt.

I'm running like a bolt of lightening. Or like a bolt.

He's/I'm bolting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:
I was sprinting so fast that the corner of my eyes became a complete blur.
I dashed in front of anything that came to my sight.
I quickened my pace until my steps became huge leaps.
Hope this helps you!